# Access a file in hadoop file system

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I have to access several files in a hadoop file system e.g. /user/.../data/somefile.txt
I have no idea how to access these files. I have a code like shown below, but this doesn't work. So I tried things like "hdfs://user/....", "hdfs://localhost:50070/user/..." or using URI somehow (altough I don't really know how this works).

I was provided hadoop version 1.2.1 for this task and I'm working with ubuntu in a virtual machine and eclipse (without hadoop plug-in). 
I've never worked with hadoop before, so it would be great if you could help me.

```
     JobConf conf = new JobConf(TotalWordCount.class); 
     conf.setJobName("wordcount"); 

     conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class); 
     conf.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class); 

     conf.setMapperClass(Map.class); 
     conf.setCombinerClass(Reduce.class); 
     conf.setReducerClass(Reduce.class); 

     conf.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class); 
     conf.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class); 

     FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path("/user/.../data/textfile.txt")); 

    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path("/user/.../output"));

    LineProcessor.initializeStopWords();

    JobClient.runJob(conf);
```

Running the code above I get an Error like this:

```
ERROR security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:ds2013 cause:org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: file:/user/.../data/textfile.txt
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: file:/user/.../data/textfile.txt
```

I also tried something like

```
 DistributedCache.addCacheFile((new Path("/user/.../data/textfile.txt")).toUri(), conf);
 Path[] paths = DistributedCache.getLocalCacheFiles(conf);
 Path cachePath = paths[0];
 BufferedReader stopListReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(cachePath.toString()));
```

But it can't find the File.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: File /user/.../data/textfile.txt does not exist.
```

Comment: What do you mean by "this doesn't work"? There could be many different error conditions.

Comment: ERROR security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:ds2013 cause:org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: file:/user/.../data/textfile.txt
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: file:/user/.../data/textfile.txt

Comment: Can you paste the content of your core-site.xml, especially the fs.default.name property?

Comment: You mean the file in this folder "hadoop-1.2.1/conf"? Or shoud that be stored in hdfs as well?  The file I found says "fs.default.name hdfs://localhost:8020"

Comment: can you try `hadoop fs -ls /user/.../data/textfile.txt` to see if you can find the file first?

Comment: remember, three slashes in a row for file: and hdfs: URIs:
`file:///user/.../data/textfile.txt`
`hdfs:///user/.../data/textfile.txt`
Make sure you're getting the right file system.

Comment: Thanks guys for your help. the problem was that you simply can't run the program within eclipse as I did. When I run the jar using the terminal it finds the paths.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for your help. the problem was that you simply can't run the program within eclipse as I did. When I run the jar using the terminal it finds the paths.

Answer (score 0):

The cause:
when you run your job directly in the eclipse, in fact, it works as local mode which means that the application will try to find the files in your client machine.

**Solution:**
In order to make sure the application can work well remotely, you need to extend the java class:Configured.java and implements Tool as the following:

```
public class SimpleMapperMain extends Configured implements Tool {
    public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
        //your code here
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int res = ToolRunner.run(new Configuration(), new SimpleMapperMain(),args);
        System.exit(res); 
    }
}
```

**note:**
1. make sure your configuration xml files, like hdfs-site.xml,core-site.xml and so on are included in the classpath, in your case, they should be placed in the src/main/resources in the maven project.
2. if it comes to permission problem, please change your current user to user:hdfs, then run the application again, the problem should be gone.

If there is any other questions, feel free to ask me.